# Downloading deployed meteor project

Tags: meteor

I have deployed an application on meteor.com long ago, I have lost my files and I currently have no way to continue the project except starting again from the scratch.

How can I download the complete project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When deploying a Meteor App, you bundle (minify and stuff) the app locally and then upload the bundle. All that now exists on Meteor's servers is bundled code. If your code wasn't on a version control service (such as GitHub) it is now definitely lost.

Comment: as far as i know, there's no way of getting files hosted in meteor domain.

Comment: I would suggest in the future think about a backup system of some sort. They range from free to like $10/mth.  Also this about using a version control system like bitbucket which is also free. Also think about what would happen if my house burnt down tonight. Would I loose everything I have worked on. Plan ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big the project was, I don't know if you'd be able to get the code back. However if it's small enough, here's an example:

http://todo.meteor.com/ - View the source, there will be a script with the source file (all of your meteor app). since you only need the code you wrote it will be at the bottom of that file.[image]

Use something like [this](http://unminify.com/) and see if you have any luck.